# ArrayAdapter<Button> displays buttons and object reference behind it in ListView

Tags: android, listview

this is my first "project" with android and I'm trying to make a single-activity app that displays a list of buttons using a listview. For some reason my ArrayAdapter displays the button correctly but behind it, it displays the object reference. So when I debug it using my phone, I see a button and right behind it its object reference.

My activity looks like this:

```
package com.example.madelenko.showcase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ArrayList<Button> projectList =
                new ArrayList<Button>();
        Button button1 = new Button(this);
        Button button2 = new Button(this);
        button1.setText("Spotify Streamer");
        button2.setText("Scores App");

        projectList.add(button1);
        projectList.add(button2);


        ArrayAdapter<Button> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<Button>(this,R.layout.element_listview_layout,
                        R.id.list_item_string,projectList);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.buttonListView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My button element layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/projectButton"
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, my listview looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.madelenko.showcase.MainActivityFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="401dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonListView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="My nanodegree apps!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Please, be patient with this newbie!

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayAdapter<Button>` is not a recommended pattern. The adapter is supposed to be adapting model objects, whether those are trivial (e.g., `ArrayAdapter<String>`) or more complex (e.g., `ArrayAdapter<Invoice>`).

So, in this case:

- You are creating an `ArrayList<Button>`, but those buttons will never be shown on the screen
- You are inflating a layout for the rows that contains a `TextView` and a `Button`; those `Button` widgets will be the ones that are shown
- You are telling `ArrayAdapter` to bind the `String` representation of the `Button` (from a call to `toString()` from the `ArrayList` to the `list_item_string` `TextView` in the row, when you create your `ArrayAdapter<Button>` instance

Also note that it is rather unusual to see buttons in `ListView` rows, since the user can click on the `ListView` rows themselves.

If you want to have a `ListView` with two rows for your two strings, you can do something like this:

```
public class ListViewDemo extends ListActivity {
  private static final String[] items={"Spotify Streamer", "Scores App"};

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        items));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I'll just use a relative layout and stack the buttons myself.